# how to apply match in loop in vba

Tags: excel, vba, loops, match

I am completely stucked with applying match function in my code.
This below is part only my code; previous part is copying cells / rows from sources to result sheet, and this planned function to check status of copy...happened or not
If match, answer OK, if not, than let empty the cell.
But simply not works and code stops each case at "res" and no idea what.
Ive learned that match has problem if result is error, so
Tried On error resume next, On error go to issues, Read same codes which works, but cannot see the problem in my one, however looking for about a week
No idea and cannot move forward however sure that solution is quite simple only my knowledge is small. Thx for reading and support me

`wsLCLHU` is source worksheet - `wsCallLCL` is result

```
Sub Match()

Dim res As Variant
'firstrow is number of first visible row of copied range of source
FirstRow = foundrow
'lastrow is last nr of row of visible range of source 
LastRow = lastrowHU
    
    For row = LastRow To FirstRow Step -1
    res = Application.Match(wsLCLHU.Range("H" & foundrow & ":" & "H" & lastrowHU).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), wsCallLCL.Range("I:I"), 0)
        
                If IsError(res) Then
                    wsLCLHU.Range("CE" & row).Value = ""
                        Else
        
                    wsLCLHU.Range("CE" & row).Value = "OK"
            
        End If
       
    Next row

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm honestly confused by your loop... you don't use your `row` within `res`, and as such it doesn't need to be inside of a loop.  If that is the case, then `res` comes out of the loop and you're writing the same value over a range, which doesn't need a loop, just `range().value = foo`.  Is this the code you're actively using?

Comment: As far as I know, MATCH search for a **single** value inside a **single** range. Your first argument is `wsLCLHU.Range("H" & foundrow & ":" & "H" & lastrowHU).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` so it's returning more than 1 value...

Comment: Guys. Len is not solution each calue is 9 char long. Main goal would be to check whether copied into CALLLCL from LCLHU the IDs of filtered column of "H" and if so, I want an OK next to it in column "CE". If so, next time when code filters again and copy paste, these items will be not copied. So copied here again corrected code but works not...no error message, but no result as well, hoever I can see copied figures properly...and here is corrected code part...res = Application.Match(wsLCLHU.Range("H" & row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), wsCallLCL.Range("I:I"), 0)

Comment: Or even I should have to use COUNTIF but tried and no result too. Maybe there is the problem with my objects here.

Comment: All made some correction like this. On this way each of the visible cells filled with OK but no "" cells however some result not match. PLs check thx>  Dim i As Long

For i = foundrow To lastrowHU

On Error Resume Next
res = WorksheetFunction.Match(rngLCLHU.Range("H" & i).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), wsCallLCL.Range("I:I"), 0)

    If IsError(res) = True Then
        rngLCLHU.Range("CE" & i).Value = ""
            Else
                rngLCLHU.Range("CE" & i).Value = "OK"
    End If

Next i

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to try explaining **in words** what you try accomplishing... I am afraid that `Application.Match` cannot process discontinuous range(s) in the way you try. It is able to return an array of marching positions, but  not in such a case.

Comment: I mean, it will not even return an array. It will always return "Error 2015", and your code cannot check anything...

Comment: FaneDuru, I can see now this comment of you..okay try to explain what I want. I have 3 large databases where each row has uniq special ID nr. I have to make week by week an update into another database, which database is a dynamic one, means I put new entries in, but others move out some old data too. If I put a row into this database, in source databases I made a match - row nr fixed as value - and next time I filter the sheet and move only "empty" cells. Hope clear now what I want to achieve with this process. Thx for reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, replace the next part of your code:

```
 For row = LastRow To FirstRow Step -1
    res = Application.Match(wsLCLHU.Range("H" & foundrow & ":" & "H" & lastrowHU).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), wsCallLCL.Range("I:I"), 0)
        
                If IsError(res) Then
                    wsLCLHU.Range("CE" & row).Value = ""
                        Else
        
                    wsLCLHU.Range("CE" & row).Value = "OK"
            
        End If
       
    Next row
```

with this one:

```
 Dim usedR As Range, rngH As Range, A As Range, C As Range

 Set usedR = wsLCLHU.UsedRange
 Set rngH = usedR.Resize(usedR.rows.count - 1).Offset(1).Columns("H:H").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) 'the H:H filtered cells range, except the header
 For Each A In rngH.Areas   'iterate between areas:
     For Each C In A.cells  'iterate between each area cells:
            Res = Application.match(C.value, wsCallLCL.Range("I:I"), 0)
            If IsError(Res) Then
                C.Offset(, 75).value = ""
            Else
                C.Offset(, 75).value = "OK"
            End If
     Next C
 Next A
```

You do not need to match more than one cell value, for each iteration...

Please, test it and send some feedback.

Comment: Hi FaneDuru I am not so well educated in this VBA and sorry if I am wrong I simply copied in this function, followed by with your suggested correction of my code. Happens nothing...I can see the range where I need the input, but cells stay empty, however cannot get back any failure message neither. What am I doing wrong? thx for your patience and support

Comment: Try explainimn IN WORDS what you try accopmlishing. I only adapt the code to make Applicatiom.Match working...

Comment: Here you are. I have 3 excel databases where each row has uniqe ID nr. I have to make week by week an update into another database, which database is a dynamic one, means I put new entries in, other members move out some old data. After input in source databases I run a match and fix the result in a control column and next time I filter the sheet and move only "empty" cells. this is like checkbox...for me not 'matching" is the main issue, but to highlight to avoid double entry. Hope clear now what I want to achieve with this process. Thx for reading

Comment: @user19102522 1. Dos your code process a **filtered range**? If yes, why? If not, why using `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`? 2. Why do you try matching many cells and **not only one, from the row you want checking**? 3. Is iteration starting with `For row = LastRow To FirstRow Step -1` done in sheet `wsLCLHU` as it should? I cannot see where you calculate `LastRow` and `FirstRow`...

Comment: Thats the case if one want to figure out something only with basic knowledge. I am novice and guess this is quite higher than my level now.  1, yes I am working on filtered ranges as first part of the code is filtering the source datasheet base on 2 criteria. and these filtered rows have to cut and copy in the result sheet.  2, this question is good guess no idea how to do it and base on what Ive read tried to built up a loop seems wrongly. Further I was thinking on too to use countif and compare 2 ranges as the result could be the same for me 3, will follow

Comment: answer to your point 3, In this section I tried to identify the starting row nr of the range of source I wanted to compare with the result, but maybe I am totally wrong with way of thinking.  Here below how I can find 1st row of filtered range...found on net and added some steps but working
Dim firstrowLCLHU As String
With rngLCLHU
  firstrowLCLHU = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).Columns(83).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1.1).Address
End With
foundRow = Range(firstrowLCLHU).row

Comment: And here is how to fing lastrowHU which is in upper part of my code....Dim lastrowHU As Long
lastrowHU = rngLCLHU.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).row

Comment: @user19102522 So, concluding that you try iterating in a filtered range of sheet `wsLCLHU` (you did not confirm that...), wanting to match each (visible) value in column "H:H" with column "I:I" from `wsCallLCL` sheet. In case of a match, write "OK" in "CE:CE" column. If no match, place in that column an empty string. Would such an understanding be correct?

Comment: Sorry yes you are right thats the case...sheet wsLCLHU column H visible/filtered range  what I want to match...option OK and leave empty perfect understanding

Comment: @user19102522 OK. I will prepare an answer. Not right now, I have something urgent to finish, but in the next minutes...

Comment: @user19102522 i will prepare the answer now. It will not take two long.

Comment: @user19102522 Please, test the updated suggested solution and send some feedback.

Comment: tested, working, huge respect, many thx for your great support...saved me a lot of time and hope I can use in the future if I understand method which takes again a time...VBA is a great option but have to learn quite much more...thank you again and have a nice day!

Comment: @user19102522 Welcome! But, where does it look too complicated? It only iterates areas (portions separated by spaces in a range) and cells of each areas. The `Match` part should be simple, I think...

Comment: accepted answer as mentioned and keep in my mind thx

Comment: solution is crystal clear but this is simple for somebody who is professional or on high level:D Me not but try to work on this...anyway what does it mean or represent ,75 in offset...where do you have this figured out? This is what I cannot absolutely not understand and cannot find any explanation on web now. thx

Comment: @user19102522 You should read about range `Offset` property... It returns a cell situated at `x` rows (nothing in our case) and `y` columns from the referenced cell. "CE:CE" column is situated at 75 columns to the cell in "H:H"... For instance, if using `C.Offset(, -1)` this will return a cell before the actual column. Something in column "G:G". And `C.Offset(1, -1)`  will return a cell in column "G:G", one row down from `C`...

Comment: @FaneDuru..sorry for this terribly stupid question...thx for answering me anyway

Answer (score 0):

Not directly answering your question, but another trick to get around using `match()` would be assessment of the length of characters of your current element versus substituting a value within that element:

```
If Not Len(Replace(namedArray(Val),phrase) = Len(namedArray(Val)) then
```

This takes some particular `phrase` and assesses if it is removed from the value in your assessed element of the `namedArray`.

Comment: Dear Cyril many thx but this is a bit hard for me to understand...how could I imagine to work with this suggestion in my case. Many thx